# What is the structure of AppxSignature.p7x?

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, authenticode, appx

Universal Windows apps are in .appx file, which is simply a zip of a bunch of files and metadata. Most of the metadata files are extensively documented on the Microsoft website and are trivial to parse and/or regenerate. However AppxSignature.p7x remains a mystery.

From this diagram ([source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsappdev/2012/12/04/designing-a-simple-and-secure-app-package-appx/)):
[image]

AppxSignature.p7x should have hashes of the AppxBlockMap.xml, content & directory hashes, and a signature. However I cannot find any documentation of the AppxSignature.p7x file itself. Ideally I would like to use an alternative tool to produce and verify this signature, e.g. openssl/gnutls or similar. A practical use for this is to update and repackage apps on Linux, and prepare .appxupload file for the Windows Store.

Comment: How signtool exactly works with APPX file is not documented (it's only documented for PE format files: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/authenticode_pe.docx), as you're supposed to use the SignerSign API on Windows (that's what signtool does undercovers). However there is an open source tool that should do what you want here called "fb-util-for-appx": https://github.com/facebook/fb-util-for-appx

Comment: @SimonMourier this is godsent stuff! This is like what I was after to re-implement! If you submit this as an answer, I'll award the bounty to you, because all that sourcecode not only documents all the trickery, but it is a ready made tool to generate appx packages on linux (and even mac too). Making appx on non-windows is what I was ultimately after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the blog post you link to, the AppxBlockMap.xml file stores cryptographic block hashes for every file in the package. This file is verified and secured with a digital signature when the package is signed using authenticode.

So, on windows, you have two tools:

- **MakeAppx.exe** that creates the package (.zip format) and the blockmap file *at the same time*. This is important, as what's in the block map corresponds closely to the .zip file bits, you can't just any zipping tool for this step, you must program the zip/app package creation using some ZIP API.
- **SignTool.exe** that adds the signature to the package using "standard" authenticode.

With the Windows API you can do the same as MakeAppx using the
[Packaging API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446766.aspx) and you can do the same as SignTool using [The SignerSign function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387733.aspx).

The whole MakeAppx process is not documented IMHO, but the blockmap schema is in fact described here: [Package block map schema reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709951.aspx) which is relatively easy to understand.

The Authenticode signature for PE document is documented here: [Windows Authenticode Portable Executable Signature Format](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/c/5/9c5b2167-8017-4bae-9fde-d599bac8184a/authenticode_pe.docx)

But it's only for PE (.dll, .exe, etc.) files (note it's also possible to sign .CAB files), and I don't think how SignerSign builds AppxSignature.p7x is documented. However, there is an open source tool here that does it here: https://github.com/facebook/fb-util-for-appx. You will notice this file https://github.com/facebook/fb-util-for-appx/blob/master/PrivateHeaders/APPX/Sign.h that declares what should be used as input for signing. I have no idea where they got that information.

Answer (score 5):

The P7X format is just 0x504B4358 ("PKCX") followed by PKCS #7 data in the DER format. DER is described by ASN.1.